# Tool tips request - causing error in IPKerrnalApp (Exception in message handler) - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tooltip

When I use the Shift + Tab short cut to bring up the tool tips in Jupyter Notebook, the anadonda prompt errors and no tool tip apears.  This only happens for some of the tool tips.
for example lens() and sum().
However, the tool tip for pd.read_csv() works.
I am running V3.11.3 of phyton and V6.5.4 of notebook.

I have two bits of information - 1)the opening of the jupyter notebook and 2)what happens when the tooltip is called.

1)The anaconda Prompt displays the following when starting Jupyter Notebook

```
  _   _          _      _
 | | | |_ __  __| |__ _| |_ ___
 | |_| | '_ \/ _` / _` |  _/ -_)
  \___/| .__/\__,_\__,_|\__\___|
       |_|

Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[W 11:38:43.423 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[C 11:38:43.423 NotebookApp] You must use Jupyter Server v1 to load JupyterLab as notebook extension. You have v2.5.0 installed.
    You can fix this by executing:
        pip install -U "jupyter-server<2.0.0"
[I 11:38:43.431 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\BenL
[I 11:38:43.431 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 11:38:43.431 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=82664f53119439026674d2912d9213f3e034ae806c051d8e
[I 11:38:43.431 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=82664f53119439026674d2912d9213f3e034ae806c051d8e
[I 11:38:43.432 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:38:43.474 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/BenL/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-22416-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=82664f53119439026674d2912d9213f3e034ae806c051d8e
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=82664f53119439026674d2912d9213f3e034ae806c051d8e
This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
```

2. When I call a tool tip it displays

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 406, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 796, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 544, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "C:\Users\BenL\anaconda3\envs\pandas_playground\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried implmenting the jedi fix
`%config Completer.use_jedi = False`
This did not solve the issue.

I have also tried re-starting the Kernerl, did not solve the issue.